# RTL right to left site

Tags: magento2.2.6

how can I change the direction of my website to be (from right to left) for languages that start from the right in magento 2.2.6
any advice, please

Answer (score 0):

In the theme css for the store, just add following style;

```
html { direction:rtl; }
```

Comment: but I wanted it to be from right to left only with arabic version

Comment: So, you're same theme for both stores?