# How can I display a multilingual store from right to left for Arabic store view?

Tags: magento2, module, layout

welcome everybody.

I'm Mostafa from Egypt, new to Magento.
I installed **magento 2.4.5** in localhost, and used the default theme "**Luma**", and added the Arabic language pack for the system, and created **two store view**, one in Arabic and one in English.

The problem I'm currently facing is that I want the **Arabic store view** to have a right-to-left display.

**How can I do that?**

thank you very much everyone.

Comment: There's [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245138/rtl-right-to-left-site) asking the same -- In your case you only want the css added to your arabic store. So I guess best way would be to create a new theme with Luma as parent, with the CSS for RTL text. Then in admin you can set the theme for your arabic store. The theme inheritance is explained [here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/inheritance/)

Comment: Just to clarify, you will have two themes in the end. Luma for EN store // Luma Child with RTL for Arabic store

Comment: You can download and install arabian language pack from here : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-arabic-language-pack.html

The link has also steps for configuration of the language for storeview.

One more blog which might point you in right direction  : https://webkul.com/blog/how-start-magento2-rtl-template/

For  RTL you may find this important : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/How-can-I-display-a-multilingual-store-from-right-to-left-for/m-p/501459

Comment: thank you for helping me.

 

I've followed the instructions in the article, and i've already created a custom theme.


Now I have a silly question if you will excuse me, in which file do I put this code html { direction:rtl; } ?